# cocos2d v3: physicsBody of a CCSprite is positioned incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm **very** new to cocos2d development.

What I am trying to implement is some sprite nodes with physics bodies. As far as I understand, you're supposed to add them to the scene like this ("physics" here is the name of CCPhysicsNode declared earlier):

```
[physics addChild:node];
```

instead of

```
[self addChild:node];
```

The second one is pretty self-explanatory, I never had any trouble with it. But with the first the position of collision shapes does not match the position of the actual sprite (as seen in debug drawing, and by offset I mean greatly offset, like 2x the actual position). This is how I declare and add the node:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"sprite.png"];
        sprite.position = position;
        sprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:[sprite boundingBox] cornerRadius:0];
        sprite.physicsBody.collisionType = @"SomeCollisionType";
        sprite.name = @"Name";
        [physics addChild:sprite];
```

What am I doing wrong? Please explain me how to make the positions match. TIA.

Comment: The position is always with respect of its parent, so how have you positioned `physics`?

Comment: I thought there is no position property for CCPhysicsNode. After [CCPhysicsNode node] I just enabled debugDraw, set the gravity, set the collision delegate and did [self addChild:physics];. Setting it to ccp(0,0) seems to do nothing.

Comment: It's a subclass of `CCNode`...  You will want to make its position `0, 0` and  content size 100% of parent.

Comment: Still no luck. Also keep in mind, that some other nodes are working just fine, though they are declared the exact same way (except different names and collision types, of course), and I'm not using SpriteBuilder.